# Start Animation Set without Java

Tags: android, android-animation, android-theme

Okay so I am trying to replace the selector animation when a person clicks on a list item.

In my styles.xml I added:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@anim/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

and the designated animation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_01" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_02" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_03" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_04" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_05" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_06" />
    <item android:duration="20" android:drawable="@drawable/notif_touch_light_07" />
</animation-list>
```

unfortunately whenever a list item is selected it just shows the first frame and does not animate. Is there anyway to animate this? Or do I have to add a clicklistener to every single list item and .start the animation when they are pressed?

Comment: maybe you could use object animator?

Comment: but I want this to be app wide, with an object animator would I not have to do this for every list item in the entire app?

Comment: you cannot do it without java, the easy solution is to extend Drawable or StateListDrawable and detect the state in `onStateChange(int[] stateSet)` method